JavaFx- SpringBoot desktop application RabbitMQ Consumer problem
I make an desktop application that has two types of input. for employee and managers.
if you want you can enter as a employee or as a manager as well, so i am planning to use this application on different computers. that is employee computer and admin computers, so i have to up this application for each computer once , this meaning 2 copy instance of application will work .
i implement rabbitMQ integration for getting message for manager computer.  If any employee add any data to database then message adding to queue and i hope admin computer application will consume this message and will add as a notification  on manager computer but it works different, because this 2 application (employee, admin) working on  2 different computer as a different instance but sharing same source code , because of this each instance has own consume method. when message adding to the queue each consumers trying to consume this queue and While listening to the message queue, they do not know which one to listen to first, and they listen sequentially, one by one, by the rabbitmq system. This is a situation that I do not want, because if the consume method in the application on the employee's computer works, this means that the consume method on the manager's computer did not work and whatever the employee adds will not be sent to the manager's computer as a notification. Is there any way to solve this? , i want only managers application consume all messeges then it will always show all notifications on managers applications .
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest



rabbitmq.queue.name= order_queue
rabbitmq.exchange.name=order_exchange
rabbitmq.routing.key=order_routing_key

package com.example.demo.config;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    @Value("${rabbitmq.queue.name}")
    private String queue;
    @Value("${rabbitmq.exchange.name}")
    private String exchange;
    @Value("${rabbitmq.routing.key}")
    private String routingKey;



    @Bean
    public Queue queue(){
        return new Queue(queue);
    }



    @Bean
    public TopicExchange exchange(){
        return new TopicExchange(exchange);
    }
    @Bean
    public Binding binding1(){
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue())
                .to(exchange())
                .with(routingKey);
    }



}
package com.example.demo.publisher;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class RabbitMQProducer {
    @Value("${rabbitmq.exchange.name}")
    private String exchange;

    @Value("${rabbitmq.routing.key}")
    private String routingKey;


    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RabbitMQProducer.class);
    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public RabbitMQProducer(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    }
    public void sendMessage(String message){
        LOGGER.info(String.format("Order sent -> %s",message));
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange,routingKey,message);
    }


}
package com.example.demo.consumer;

import com.example.demo.controller.MainFrameController;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class RabbitMQConsumer {

    MainFrameController mainFrameController;



    public RabbitMQConsumer(MainFrameController mainFrameController) {
        this.mainFrameController = mainFrameController;
    }

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RabbitMQConsumer.class);

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbitmq.queue.name}")
    public void consume(String message){


        LOGGER.info(String.format("Received Order ->%s", message));
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                VBox notificationVbox = mainFrameController.getNotification_Vbox();
                if (notificationVbox != null) {
                    Label label = new Label(message);
                    notificationVbox.getChildren().add(0, label);
                } else {
                    LOGGER.warn("Notification VBox is null.");
                }
            });

    }



}


